# Is there a collective word for describing synonyms, antonyms, etc?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, hypernyms

I'm trying to create a phrase stating:

> Homonyms are my favorite [descriptor here].

However, I'm not having any luck finding anything that collectively describes words like synonym, antonym and homonym. I thought it may be a word class, but that's not it since that describes words like noun, determiner, adjective, etc.

---

Is there collective word for describing synonyms, antonyms and the like as a whole?

Comment: What, you mean like names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you're looking for is a rather abstract concept I don't think there's a word for all the collective terms. After all, you're trying to lump things like acronyms, contranyms, paronyms, synonyms and antonyms all into one. The closest I can really find (going off the original etymology here and meaning of the suffix -nym meaning 'name') is probably just *inter-word-class* as it accurately describes that you're classifying the **difference between a word and another entity rather than the word itself.**

The problem now is phrasing it in a way that doesn't seem overly long or difficult to interpret, which I don't think is really possible. It would be like lumping all the words with a -osis suffix together. It's far too abstract to even cat

Honestly, I think you're fine with *word-class* or even *name-class*. There's no real ambiguity there with prefacing your statement with the word homonym :)